# How to find the active (real) power of source A of this circuit?

Tags: power, capacitor, power-electronics, inductor, reactive-power

What is making difficult here for me is the fact that the two voltage sources are in series (or I think that they are). This is something which I did not face before. I am well aware of why Source A is delivering energy which is because it is following active convention. What I do not understand is how this active power is calculated using the information that is given. I have all the formula related to active,reactive, apparent and complex power, but I am finding it difficult on how to calculate active power of A. Help will be appreciated!
[image]

Comment: the active power defines if the source is delivering or absorbing. if it is positive or negative.

Comment: @PaulGhobril yes I know that, but how is the information that are given enough to find active power for source A?

Comment: *What I do not understand is how this active power is calculated using the information that is given.* <-- you need to explain why you are having difficulty so someone can guide you away from that specific difficulty.

Comment: @Andyaka how do I find the current in this circuit even though the two voltages are in series?

Comment: You start by finding the voltage across the R and L. Clearly that is Va - Vb

Comment: if you use the complex notation it will be simple to find out the current and the power. Active power is the real part.

Comment: Have a look at slide 6 of my recent [seminar](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Introduction%20to%20the%20DAB.pdf) on the dual-active-bridge inverter DAB) with sinusoidal sources. Active power \$P\$ in watts is obtained by integrating (or averaging) the instantaneous power \$p(t)=v(t)i(t)\$ over a cycle.